# Swift UITableView inside UIScrollView Touches Issue

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have read every single article why my uitableview touches are not being called and tried every solution with no success. Basically I have

- UIScrollView

  - UITableView

    - UITableViewCell

      - UIButton

After I scroll the the UIScrollView my touches to the tableviewcell button stop working. Now I am using Swift 2.0 with Autolayout also I have tried everything and no success. More info is that my tableview scroll is dissabled since I load the products and set the tableview height to be the height of the cell multiplied of the total count of cells and if I have 10 cells and each cell height is 100 my tableview height will be 1000 and I need to scroll the UIScrollView in order to browse threw the cells. Problem is that I can't figure it out how to enable my tableviewcell touches:

Comment: What's your purpose for using the UIScrollView at all?

Comment: Because inside the UIScrollview I also have User Profile Image, username, other buttons, labels and then the uitableview

Comment: And you need it all to scroll together as if it's in the same table? Just use a table view with multiple different sections and types of cells.

Comment: I think you can add user profile image, user name etc in the table header section if you want to put header always on top.
Or you can use table header view if you don't want to put header on top always..

Then there will be no need for the scroll view.